# Inserting into DB Table using SQL query based on a test performed on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe `df` like below:

```
Serviceday  Proj
16-Feb-2019  0
17-Feb-2019  1
17-Feb-2019  0
17-Feb-2019  0
16-Feb-2019  0
18-Feb-2019  0
```

Now if `Proj` is 1 at least **once** for each unique `Serviceday`, then for that particular `Serviceday` the `Projected` column in my Database table should be set to 1 otherwise 0.

Like here the `Projected` column for Servicedays 16th & 18th should be 0 and for 17th should be 1 inside my DB Table.
Basically i need to update my Database table based on this test performed on pandas dataframe.

How to write a function which will have a for loop for performing the test and then a SQL query for inserting into the database?

The DB i am using is Oracle12c

Comment: Why would it involve a python `for` loop?

Comment: else how will you check for which all servicedays proj was at least once 1. I think to perform this check, we will need to iterate through the entire df. Or if you have a better approach... :)

Comment: into which Database( Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres ..etc. )..? Since it matters by imported class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this. Sum up the Proj column for each ServiceDay. If it is greater than 0 then Projected=1, else Projected=0. To write to database use the dataframe's [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method.

```
df1=df.groupby('ServiceDay').Proj.agg('sum').to_frame()
df1['Projected']=(df1.Proj>0).astype('uint8')
df1.drop(['Proj'], axis=1)
df1.to_sql(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only two values, 0 and 1, consider `transform`:

```
df['Proj'] = df.groupby(['Serviceday'])['Proj'].transform('max')

df
#     Serviceday  Proj
# 0  16-Feb-2019     0
# 1  17-Feb-2019     1
# 2  17-Feb-2019     1
# 3  17-Feb-2019     1
# 4  16-Feb-2019     0
# 5  18-Feb-2019     0
```

Then append accordingly with `to_sql` using an SQLAlchemy connection.

```
df.to_sql(name='mytable', con=myengine, index = False, if_exists='append')
```

Alternatively with a cursor execution using list of lists from `DataFrame.values()`:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO mytable (Serviceday, Proj) VALUES (:1, :2);'''

mycur.executemany(sql, df[['Serviceday', 'Proj']].values.tolist())   
myconn.commit()
```

Comment: `dsdbcur = self.dsdbcon.cursor()

 insert_ds_cal = '''insert into ds_calendar (calendarday, projected) values (%s, %s);'''

 dsdbcur.executemany(insert_ds_cal, proj_list[['CALENDARDAY', 'PROJECTED']].values.tolist())
        self.dsdbcon.commit()` I am doing this but getting error "dsdbcur.executemany(insert_ds_cal, proj_list[['CALENDARDAY', 'PROJECTED']].values.tolist())
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number". I wonder what could possibly be wrong here? `@Parfait`

Comment: Issue is the parameter placeholder, `%s`, not supported by your DB-API. This is why you should always tag your database, `oracle` and show the DB-API you use such as `cx_Oracle`. I assumed the more popular APIs. See edit and [docs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html) (Many at Once section at bottom).